# Building a container with gcloud, kubectl and python3.6

Tags: dockerfile, python-3.6, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

I want my deployment pipeline to run a python 3.6 script on my GKE hosted database.

For that, locally, I use `kubectl port-forward` then run the script successfully.

However, to run it in my pipeline I need to start a container that will support both GKE access and python3.6

To run python3.6 I'm using the image `python:3.6`

To run `gcloud` and `kubectl` I'm using the image `google/cloud-sdk:latest`

However, gcloud is using python2, hence making it very difficult for me to orchestrate a container that will include all of these tools.

For reference, I'm using Bitbucket Pipelines. Might be able to solve it with the services feature, but currently its too complicated since I need to run many commands on both potential containers.

Comment: It should be possible to combine tools that depend on python2 and python3 using virtualenv.

Comment: But, I think perhaps there's a better way. I suspect your `gcloud` requirement is so that you can `gcloud cluster get-credentials`. Once you have the credentials, these are persisted in `~/.kube/config` and, if you prune this file to ensure only the desired account, cluster are included, this may suffice and then just need `kubectl` which is a go binary. You should (I have not done this) be able to authenticate using a service account (preferable) rather than a human account.

Comment: Hmmm :-( I was incorrect. `~/.kube/config` retains a dependency on `gcloud config config-helper`. There must be a way to authenticate to GKE using a GCP service account without requiring `gcloud`.

Comment: You piqued my curiosity. Have a look at this: https://medium.com/google-cloud/authing-w-kubernetes-engine-service-accounts-ae752b46ed18